# HTML Table within "tabs" and header freezing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsfiddler example with the html and tab setup here http://jsfiddle.net/3GLD7/6/

The production will have many tabs each with it's own table. I'm looking to have the tables inside the tabs scroll and keep their headers frozen. I've tried using http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-To-Freeze-Header-Row-In-Table-freezeheader/ but the header columns when I start scrolling has it's position much lower and it shows up over the data itself. I'm thinking maybe the fact that I use tabs messes it up? I'm not a CSS guy by any means so wondering if someone could lend a hand?

Could the tabs be the thing that screws this up.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#Test1">Test1</a>
            </li>
    </ul>

        <div id="Test1">
            <div id="HOT-Test1" style="width: 1100px; height: 800px;">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so do you want to have the tabs frozen as well as the table headers? Something similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/3GLD7/7/

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't work. When I'm all the way up the headers sort of sit on top of the first row a little, and when I scroll I can see the data scrolling behind everything. These are the little issues that I always get with this stuff and what I'm seeing if anyone has a solution for those. I tested yours in Chrome and IE and they both show the data behind the headers and tabs. Plus the header columns don't line up with the data columns.